# How to Extract integer from an input of this Format in which each attribute is separated by “:”

Tags: java, testcase

> Create a class IPLTeam with the attributes Teamname, player1Amount,player2Amount, player3Amount, player4Amount, and remMoney (int). Add a parameterized constructor called IPLTeam(String name, int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4)

Your program must use an array of objects to get the eight team’s details.
Create a Function called calculateMoney(), to compute the remaining amount for each team and
display the Team Name with the remaining amount for each team.

**Input format:**

Each attribute is separated by “:”

**TeamName:First_player_amt:Second_player_amt:Third_player_amt:Fouth_player_amt**

Inputs are in the form of Strings that are separated by space

Example:

CSK:15:12:10:8

```
import java.util.*;

class IPLTeam 
{
     String Teamname;
     int player1Amount, player2Amount, player3Amount, player4Amount, remMoney;
     public IPLTeam(String name, int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4) 
     {
        Teamname = name;
        player1Amount = p1;
        player2Amount = p2;
        player3Amount = p3;
        player4Amount = p4;
     }
void calculateMoney() {}
}

public class Main 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         String name;
         int p1, p2, p3, p4;
         IPLTeam[] objarr = new IPLTeam[8];
         for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
         {
             name = sc.nextLine();
             p1 = sc.nextInt();
             p2 = sc.nextInt();
             p3 = sc.nextInt();
             p4 = sc.nextInt();
             objarr[i] = new IPLTeam(name, p1, p2, p3, p4);
         }
         sc.close();
     } 
 }
```

I Have just Done the Basic object Array Input

Can anyone tell me how to extract the integer from the following input format and make sure that we need to extract only the integer, not the string present in the input (eg: CSK).

Make sure to check the example given above

Answer (score 0):

You could just tell Scanner to use ":" as a delimiter. `useDelimiter( "[:\n\r]");`.

```
public class ParseColon {

   private static final String testVector = "My name:4:3:2:1";

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner( testVector);
      sc.useDelimiter( "[:\n\r]");
      String name;
      int p1, p2, p3, p4;
//      IPLTeam[] objarr = new IPLTeam[ 8 ];
      for( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {
         name = sc.next();
         p1 = sc.nextInt();
         p2 = sc.nextInt();
         p3 = sc.nextInt();
         p4 = sc.nextInt();
         System.out.printf( "%s %d %d %d %d\n", name, p1, p2, p3, p4 );
      }

   }
}
```